# How to solve this second order DE question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this DE?

$(\cos y+p)y''+q{ (y') }^{ 2 }+r=0$

where $p, q, r$ are constants.

I know that this a type of second order DE whose solution is given as $y=CF+PI$. Here the $PI$ is $0$.
Generally it can be represented as, $$a{ D }^{ 2 }+bD+c=0$$
Now we can solve this as a quadratic equation and write the solution. But I'm stuck at this because of the power on $y'$.

Comment: Please list your progress or show us where you seem to have a problem?

Comment: Numerically. Second-order nonlinear differential equations generally don't have closed form solutions. Do you have some reason to think this one does?

Comment: Is $p$ totally random ? Especially, is it possible that $p\in (-1,1)$ ?

Comment: It's not homogeneous --- not with that $r$ in it.

Comment: Sorry, edited it. I confused it with something else.

Comment: That power on the $y'$ is what makes it nonlinear and blows your assumed solution out of the water.

Comment: Yes I got it that its non-linear and I haven't encountered this type of problem before. Can you teach me?

Comment: @Hyperbola, Why don't you start from small cases mon cher? Take $r = 0$, then maybe vary the ranges of $p,q,r$ and try out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polyanin's [EqWorld](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0344.pdf) proposed the nice substitution $\;w(y):=(y')^2\,$ to rewrite $\,(\cos y+p)\,y''+q(y')^2+r=0\;$ as :
$$\frac{\cos y+p}2\,w'(y)+q\;w(y)+r=0$$
(since $\,\displaystyle\;2\;y'\,y''=\frac d{dx}w(y)=\frac d{dy}w(y)\frac {dy}{dx}=y'\,w'(y)\,$ and ignoring the case $\,\frac {dy}{dx}=0\,$ here...)

To solve the resulting first order linear ODE begin with the homogenous ODE :
$$\frac {dw}w=-\frac{2q\,dy}{\cos y+p}$$
to get :
$$\log(w)=C-2q\int \frac {dy}{\cos y+p}$$
that you may solve with the $\,t:=\tan\left(\frac y2\right)$ [substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) 
to get [Alpha's result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28-2/%28cos%28y%29%2bp%29,y%29).
Adding a trivial solution of the complete linear ODE should give you [Alpha's complete result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%28cos%28y%29%2bp%29%2aw%27%28y%29%2b2%2aq%2aw%28y%29%2b2%2ar=0) :
$$(y')^2=w(y)=C_1\; \exp\left[{\frac{4\,q\;\operatorname{atanh\left(\tan\left(\dfrac y2\right)\dfrac{p-1}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}}\right]-\dfrac rq$$

With all this work we still only have an expression of the square of $y'$ as a function of $y$.
This should be helpful to study the phase space of the solution but far from an explicit solution.

We may obtain $x$ in function of $y$ by rewriting this as (up to a constant) :
$$x=\int \frac {dy}{\sqrt{C_1\,\exp\left[\dfrac{4\,q\;\operatorname{atanh\left(\tan(y/2)\;(p-1)/\sqrt{1-p^2}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}\right]-\frac rq}}$$
(or $\sqrt{-\cdots}$ in the denominator) but I am not sure that a closed form may be found even if we ignore the additional constants...

Comment: I didn't expect at all this to be solvable!

Comment: @O.I: $y''$ beside the lone $y'^2$ was kind of encouraging but I remain compassionate with the endeavor of people like Polyanin, Marichev and the many russian (and others) searching and collecting all these symmetries ! Cheers,

Comment: @O.I.: I must add that the final result is just $y'^2=w(y)$ so...

Comment: Nice, but can you edit that last display so as to make the exponent visible without a microscope?

Comment: Thanks @Gerry I'll edit my answer...